# VB.Net equivalent Calculation Of Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, math

first of all i am sorry for asking this very noob type question, but i face this very first time of my life.

I need to do a calculation in vb.net but the formula is from javascript.

It's a very simple formula. But when i try, vb.net shows error % is not a valid char :(

Here is the formula: (in js)

```
var s = (a % b + c % d);
```

i know it's a very easy solution for someone who know even very basic of arithmetic calculation.

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` is also called Modulus, it divides two numbers and returns the remainder of division, in VB.NET you use the `Mod` operator for this:

```
Dim s As integer = (a Mod b + c Mod d)
```

If a, b, c or d are doubles or floats however, you need to cast `s` as a double or float, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator#example-1).

Answer (score 1):

As floating type

```
Dim s As double = a Mod b + c Mod d
```

As integer type

```
Dim s As integer = a Mod b + c Mod d
```

Comment: if some numbers are floats, then yes.